# Visual Studio 2008 Publish Fails

Tags: visual-studio-2008, publishing

HI everyone, i need some advice regarding Visual Studio 2008 Pro.

We develop a lot of web service applications and ever since we started we keep encountering an error on our production server that does not seem to occur on the development or test systems.

When publishing new code to the server we are normally met with the following error.

Publish Failed : Bad Gateway : Status Line Invalid. (very similar to this our dev team were not able to provide me a screenshot or exact wording unfortunatly).

even though we get this error the web service always functions 100% the way we expect it to. has anyone else come across this error ? or a solution / reason for it ?

the PC doing the publish is a windows xp SP3 system, the server we are publishing too is a fully patched windows 2003 server box.

The test and Dev servers we have are pretty much clones of the production system and like i mentioned when publishing to test / dev we get no hint of this problem or error it only ever shows up when publishing live.

If it makes a diff, the test / dev servers are on the same network addresses as the client PC (10.0.0.x) whereas the production server is on a different network range (192.168.0.x) With a Firewall between them.

This problem only ever seems to rear its ugly head on one particular project, other programs (webservices if thats the correct term) publish to the same server without incident.

thanks for any help guys

Kris

Comment: Developers that can't screenshot or the wording of an error message? quality developers. Can they reproduce the error? does it happen every time or intermittently?

Comment: Hi Maslow, this error happens every single time we try to publish this project but as mentioned it only ever occurs on our live server, never on the internal environment which makes it difficult to test fixes or possible solutions.

Comment: The exact error message is 'Bad gateway: status-line invalid'.  It happens every time.  The publish does seem to work, but it looks as though VS is having trouble interpreting the response back through the socket, hence giving an HTTP 502 error.  Anyone had this problem?

Comment: How is the publish set up?  Admin share, server share, ftp, etc?

Comment: The webserver has Frontpage Server Extensions installed and configured so the developers just take advantage of this to-do the publish from.

Comment: Sorry, you were given slightly incorrect initial information - it's Visual Studio 2005 Professional Edition.

Also, we have tried publishing to this machine by IP address and by domain name.  It does seem to publish the main project files, but dependent files (such as MySQL .NET Connector DLL) need to be placed there manually.

Comment: this also seems to be a problem with new projects but with no guaranteed certainty, sometimes it publishes perfectly other times it fails all together and as Jaymie mentions above sometimes it only partially fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK This problem has been resolved. turned out to be something a lot simpler than expected.

we use sub-domains of our main website to point to servers within our network, for publishing etc (this was the late idea of a previous IT Person). what we have found is publishing to these domain names generates the Bad Gateway error pretty much constantly.

however using the internal network ip of the server never generates this problem.

it seems to be down to how we have the domains configured and the routing through the firewall which is causing this problem. although we are going about doing the publishes in a very round about way.

the solution to us was to use the internal IP addresses to publish to the servers rather than a domain that pointed to external IP's that routed through the firewall.